# Possible read webconfig AppSetting in html?

Tags: asp.net, html, web-config

i want to grab an AppSetting key from my webconfig in a regular .htm file - is this possible to do?

Normally id make it into an aspx file so i can do some codebehind something similar but the htm is out in the wild and i dont think i can change the url

*Webconfig*

```
<add key="SomeLocation" value="http://my.ip.address/"/>
```

*Htm Markup*

```
<a href="<%=MyCodeBehind()%>">Contact Us</a>
```

*VB.Net Codebehind*

```
    Public ReadOnly Property MyCodeBehind() As String
    Get
        Return General.GetAppSetting("SomeLocation")
    End Get
End Property
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file that is not generated with any server-side processing cannot possibly include any additional data, *per se*.

You do have a few options (if I understand your problem correctly):

- You can reconfigure the server to process ".htm" as an ASPX page and use your code behind.
- You can redirect the specific URL to an ASPX page from the web server using [rewrite rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)

Comment: Ya i'm pretty limited - the "SomeLocation" changes depending on where it sits, plus we have a convension to put these kinds of things in the config file. It being an HTM makes it inflexible.

I guess i can always hardcode it, i dont have access to the production server - and it might be more trouble than its wroth to reconfigure it

unless theres a way to redirect 1 specific htm? not all of them